# Powershell OS check before running a command using an IF statement

Tags: powershell, operating-system, message-queue

Is there a way to check the OS that a PowerShell script is running on, and make an `If` Statement which says:

[pseudo code]

```
if its this OS 
    do this 
if its this other OS 
    do this
```

Only for a certain line in the script? I have to make a PowerShell script that is setting up private message queues. Sadly, some of the clients of my company don't use Windows Server 2012, so the way more simple version of adding a private message queue wont work on Windows Server 2008 and the outdated PowerShell version. To resolve this problem, I have to also put in the massively complex old way of doing it instead, but I want both methods to be there.

Comment: Sorry i meant "if statement" not loop.

Comment: Sorry but this seems like a rather trivial request. Have you looked up how to get the OS Version. WMI perhaps..... Then you could use a `switch` statement  to action based on results. Example for starting: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/12/08/hey-scripting-guy-december-8-2009.aspx

Comment: sorry im still pretty new to powershell, and also new to here so i wasnt sure how to phrase that the way you edited it. oh yes i suppose i could use a switch statement and have the user pick which OS, though i was hoping to automate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get operating system without using WMI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937087/get-operating-system-without-using-wmi)

Comment: That linked question shows you how to get it 2 different ways.

Comment: ahh thanks ill try that too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Switches would be cleaner, but since you asked how to do it that specific way...

Set your variable to check against OS version (lifted from linked thread [Get operating system without using WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937087/get-operating-system-without-using-wmi)):

```
$OSVersion = (get-itemproperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -Name ProductName).ProductName
```

Construct your IF statement:

```
If($OSVersion -eq "Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard")
{
Write-Host "Hooray It's Server 2K8 r2!"
Invoke-Item "C:\Pictures\Hooray.jpg"
}
ElseIf($OSVersion -eq "Windows 7 Professional")
{
Write-Host "Okay, Windows 7 is cool, too!"
Invoke-Item "C:\Pictures\Smiley.jpg"
}
ElseIf($OSVersion -eq "Windows Vista")
{
Write-Host "What have I done with my life?!"
Invoke-Item "C:\Pictures\GunToHead.jpg"
}
ElseIf($OSVersion -eq "Windows Millennium Edition")
{
Write-Host "Go away, operating system.  You are drunk."
Invoke-Item "C:\Pictures\LiquorAndHiccups.jpg"
}
```

Hope that helps.  I'm assuming you're new to PowerShell, but when you get comfortable, start learning switches.

Comment: i am new and i do know how to use switches, just not that well i guess lol. ive used it in the past for things like asking the user to put in a number and when they do that number it does a thing

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who's new to [switches](https://ss64.com/ps/switch.html) here's the Switch statement equivalent of @Nate's answer for comparison.  There's also more [advanced](https://www.sevecek.com/EnglishPages/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=19) ways you can choose with them (including regex), and if they get truly complicated you can move the tests to well named functions

```
$OSVersion = (get-itemproperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -Name ProductName).ProductName

switch ($OSVersion)
{
    "Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard"
    {
        Write-Host "Hooray It's Server 2K8 r2!"
        Invoke-Item "C:\Pictures\Hooray.jpg"
    }
    "Windows 7 Professional"
    {
        Write-Host "Okay, Windows 7 is cool, too!"
        Invoke-Item "C:\Pictures\Smiley.jpg"
    }
    "Windows Vista"
    {
        Write-Host "What have I done with my life?!"
        Invoke-Item "C:\Pictures\GunToHead.jpg"
    }
    "Windows Millennium Edition"
    {
        Write-Host "Go away, operating system.  You are drunk."
        Invoke-Item "C:\Pictures\LiquorAndHiccups.jpg"
    }
}
```